# Disable linking for a specific library

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linker

In Visual Stuido 2008, I am getting "warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc60.pdb' was not found with ..." The problem is the .lib file containing this specific .obj file is not a "project" that I can specifically tell to generate/not generate debug info for. If possible, I do not want to simply ignore the warning. Is there any way to tell my project to not link this library?

Answer (score 0):

Try linker options->ignore default libraries - if you don't use them, you dont have to keep references. If using this option, no library linked, if you did not told to link.

Comment: If I do this, then I get compile errors, so I guess I cannot ignore it. I do have a vc90.pdb file, but not the vc60.pdb file that it is looking for. Could the vc90 file be the correct one? If so how could I link the library to this pdb file? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Project properity->Linker options->Debugging->Generate program database file. Here you can set the .pdb's name. Or just turn it off.